# How to use Console.ReadLine() in a while statement

Tags: c#, string, console-application, do-while

Im looping a question untill the user puts in the value i want to accept. In this case its a number with a dash and it should be 7 'symbols' long.

My problem is putting the ReadLine inside of the while() statement.

So this is my code:

```
string cpr = "";
do
{

cpr = Console.ReadLine(); //I dont want ReadLine here :/

} while (
//I want Console.ReadLine() here
cpr.Length != 7
&&
!Regex.IsMatch(cpr, @"^[0-9-]+$")
&&
Regex.IsMatch(cpr, @"^[a-z]+$")
);
```

Putting ReadLine in a while statement is possible i have some other code that works while try parsing an int

```
do
{
//do something here
} while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int1));
```

Comment: I am very confused as to what the problem is, why do you care that the `Console.ReadLine()` is in the `do` block?

Comment: Its not necessary
I guess im stubborn an eager to know !

Comment: Do u want not to hit enter after the 7th character.or what?

Comment: I don't think you have the concept of do while loops correct. The code is supposed to execute(do) a block of code at least once and then repeatedly executes the block, or not, depending on a given condition(while)

Comment: its for a number thats supposed to be like
birthdate plus four digits seperated by dash

"ddmmyy-xxxx"

I have a clear plan for how to make most, but now im stuck on the ReadLine thing

Comment: Not to detract from the question itself, but you really should add some proper indentation to your code. It would be far more readable, especially once things start to get nested.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb Not really sure what indentation is. Ive tried googling a bit. Do you mean comments? Thanks for ur feedback though

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
            string cpr = "";
            bool condition = true;
            while (condition )
            {
                cpr = Console.ReadLine();
                if(cpr is ok)
                {
                    condition = false;
                }
            }
```

Comment: What are you trying to show with `cpr is ok`? I get that this is just a simple example, but this isn't going to compile...

Comment: Thanks, ill try that !

Comment: So i should put my do while condition inside the while parentheses in your example?

Comment: In my examlple I proposed you whille loop instead of do while loop. I dont know exactly what you are trying to achieive, but in this way I moved condition inside while, and removed 'do' part completely.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with the comments (in that this isn't the *best* way to approach this - in fact, the code you've provided is more than adequate), you can do assignment inside of a conditional statement. ie.

```
var str = "";
do
{
...
} while ((str = Console.ReadLine()).Length != 7 && Regex.IsMatch(str, ...));
```

Except in this case, you'd need to use a while loop, instead of a do-while (since you won't capture input until the end of the loop with the do-while pattern).

Comment: Thanks, ill try this also !